# SQLLDR Oracle Data Import, Date Format = yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11gr2

I am trying to import data from a flat file into Oracle 11gr2 using SQLLDR, and i have 3 columns with date formats like "yyyy-mm-dd".  Oracle keeps throwing errors when I try to import the data like this.  Is there a quick solution to just import the data in this format?  I would prefer to not have to change the format of the data in the file since it is very large.

Here is an example of the error listed in the log.ct:

> Record 51: Rejected - Error on table LINEITEM, column L_SHIPDATE.
>   ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Thanks!

Comment: you could force the format by writing ..., MyField  "TO_DATE(:MyField, 'yyyy-MM-dd')", ... in your CTL-file

Answer (score 1):

Trying casting the date format as mentioned below, in your control card (Control file)

```
YourColumn DATE "YYYY-MM-DD"
```

Comment: Did you mean to write *control file*?

Comment: yup.. got used to call it control card here, due to frequent interaction with mainframe group.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT

```
#>export NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD'
```